# matrix with pure imaginary eigenvalue which is of different geometric and algebraic multiplicity

Tags: linear-algebra

I am looking for a **real** matrix A having the following properties:

1. the eigenvalues of A all have real parts that are zero or negative
2. pure imaginary eigenvalue(s) of A exist
3. the geometric multiplicity and algebraic multiplicity of some pure
   imaginary eigenvalue(s) are different.

Comment: how would you get an imaginary value my multiplying real numbers together.

Comment: I'm not sure about the terminology.  Does 'geometric multiplicity' mean the number of corresponding eigenvectors, and 'algebraic multiplicity' mean the multiplicity of the eigenvalue as a root of the characteristic equation?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of the polynomial $(x^2+1)^2$.

Comment: Hi, Brent. Thank you for your help. Now I see your answer in the previous post. I missed it